# Delay in mouse movement when using both the keyboard & mouse simultaneously

Tags: keyboard, windows-8.1, mouse, touchpad, delay

I got a new Lenovo Flex 2 15 a couple of days ago, and the laptop is working pretty well.
However, when I use the keyboard then quickly attempt to move the mouse with the touchpad, I am unable to move the mouse for at least half a second-or-so.

The exact same question exists [here](https://superuser.com/questions/758730/no-way-to-allow-simultaneous-typing-and-mouse-movement), but however it has no responses.
I've already gone into the Windows 8.1 'PC Settings' and set the touchpad delay setting to 'No Delay (always on)':

[image]

I have looked in the Control Panel's Mouse settings and the settings for the touchpad, but nothing references to this behaviour.

How can I remove this delay so I can use both the keyboard and mouse at the same time?
My laptop also is equipped with a touch-screen, so perhaps this has something to do with it?

***Edit: Not a hardware issue, the Synaptic icon in the taskbar shows that the system recognises when I do, say, Ctrl+Z + move the touchpad; it's just that the actual mouse on the screen isn't moving.***

Comment: Take a look at your synaptic specific settings. There might be a setting to "disable touchpad while typing". If this is set, then it will override OS settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On touchpads made by Synaptics, this is a "user-comfort" feature called PalmCheck.** Touchpad operation is intentionally blocked when you are pressing keys on built-in keyboard.

You can **disable the feature** in control panel **"Mouse"** by minimizing PalmCheck sensitivity. Open mouse control panel and follow yellow highlights from top to bottom:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When changing the 'delay' setting to "No Delay (always on)" does not
work, go to regedit and follow this registry path:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER>Software>Microsoft>Windows>CurrentVersion>PrecisionTouchPad`

Then change "AAPThreshold" from 2 (or, whatever value is set) to 0.

You may have to reboot for changes to take effect.

The behavior may also be down to the drivers; so if the above did not work,
ensure that they are up to date.
Driver updates are usually found in Windows Update, Optional updates section.

Comment: That value is actually currently `0`: http://puu.sh/c1uHO/38dd470698.png

Comment: Conclusion: According to the documentation there should be no delay, but there is still one on your computer. You could try to find a newer driver in Windows Update or on the Lenovo site. Failing that, you could try to get in touch with Lenovo Support. As I don't have your model and cannot check further, this is as far as I can go.

Comment: Model is Lenovo Flex 2 15 (I wrote it in the original question).

Comment: I knew that when I wrote the above comment. I don't have that model, so I could only give advice "that usually works", but evidently not for you.

Comment: @cybermonkey – No need of these Registry stunts on Lenovo laptops with Synaptics touchpads. **Just [disable the PalmCheck](http://superuser.com/a/1015567/287473)** and you are fine (as well as I am on my Lenovo laptop.)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like more of a hardware issue than a settings issue.  Given the large amount of hits with "Flex 2 touchpad issues" you're likely going to experience this issue until you switch to using an external keyboard and mouse or replace the laptop.  That said there are several things to try.

1. Try using the laptop while unplugged.  Apparently it's possible that the battery can become overcharged and affect keyboard and touchpad functionality [like this](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Idea-Windows-based-Tablets-and/Lenovo-flex-2-14-keyboard-and-touchpad-giving-irregular-response/td-p/1697009)
2. Uninstall and reinstall the touchpad.  It's possible that it could be conflicting with the keyboard interrupts.
3. Uninstall and reinstall the keyboard.  Same thing as above though it's a toss-up as to which one could be causing the conflict.
4. Factory Reset via the "Novo Button" (see page 26 of the [user's guide](http://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/user_guides/ideapad_flex_ug_en.pdf))
5. [System Refresh](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc) with Windows 8.1

Hopefully one of these things work, worse comes to worse try to connect with [Lenovo Support](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/landingpage/contact/) and go from there.  Might be worthwhile to look into the return policy for where you made your purchase and try to get a different laptop should you continue to struggle.

Comment: My system has a DVD drive, and as such doesn't actually have the 'Novo' button, only the power button there is present. Not a hardware issue, the Synaptic icon in the taskbar shows that the system recognises when I do, say, Ctrl+Z + move the touchpad; it's just that the actual mouse on the screen isn't moving.

Answer (score 1):

It's really simple, and it's not an operating system issue - it's just PalmCheck being set to default. See this link for instructions on how to fix PalmCheck. Use Jeremy Gutjahr's reply; the Microsoft support woman has no idea what she's talking about.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/mouse-delay-between-typing-and-using-mouse/183a7da4-0ecf-4538-ae73-33d94ec0bb75?auth=1

Comment: External links can break, in which case your answer wouldn't contain the solution.  For this reason, we ask that you include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Answers that are links to an answer somewhere else tend to attract downvotes and are usually deleted.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The delay experience is due to discrepancies between the IO buffers and communication with your OS. When you press a key *and* simultaneously move the mouse that information has to be moved to keyboard's and mouse's buffer. Their controllers will then generate an interrupt and forward it to the operating system to pass the events, however it is overwhelmed by having the simultaneous interrupts from the mouse and the keyboard, thus experiencing the delays. This is an inevitable consequence of non concurrent process..Also try this in *any* OS and you will experience similar results.

Comment: 30 seconds to process an interrupt? Come on, be serious!

Comment: Not a hardware issue, the Synaptic icon in the taskbar shows that the system recognises when I do, say, Ctrl+Z + move the touchpad; it's just that the actual mouse on the screen isn't moving.

Comment: I will stand by this answer until you pry my cold dead body off of it.....

Comment: Was to do with how Windows 8.1 handles it, not the hardware. I installed Windows 7 Professional and no longer have the issue.