# How can I get my lenovo ideapad to let me click the mouse and use the keyboard at the same time, when the palm sensitivity slider is greyed out?

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, lenovo-laptop

So, there are a lot of problems with my Lenovo touchpad that seem to be preexisting at the time of manufacture.  The cursor can't be moved at the same time as most keys are pressed, nor can mouseclicks be registered.  There seem to be exceptions for the 'shift' key and 'ctrl' key, and the delay between registering the pgdn/pgup has been pressed once and registering that it is being held allows the mouse to be briefly used with those keys.

The problem is that I need to hold down the 'z' key and click to use some software (ctrl+click and shift+click are already used).  Also, the situation is just annoying in general so it'd be nice to fix it for general use as well.

I have found a couple sites that suggest the problem should be able to be fixed by editing a registry field in the touchpad driver, specifically [DisableWhenType_Enable needs to be set to 0](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-B-and-G-Series-Notebooks/G505s-touchpad-not-working-while-typing/m-p/1399543#M24427) (why is this even a thing...), but my ideapad has a Synaptics touchpad, whose registry folders have no such line (and altering any line in the folder seems to have no effect on the problem).  My OS is Windows 10.

I've also been directed to [Delay in mouse movement when using both the keyboard & mouse simultaneously](https://superuser.com/questions/819273) , this top answer to which almost works.  My touchpad is definitely manufactured by Synaptics (it's V8.1, apparently), and there is a 'Palm Sensitivity' option enabled, but there's no way to disable or adjust it; there is a slider but the slider is greyed out and no portion of that setting responds to input.

The answer in that question regarding registries does, in fact, lead to a registry folder named 'PrecisionTouchPad'.  The options therein are:

AAPThreshold (set to 0 from initial value of 2, no change)
CursorSpeed (at default 10)
EnableEdgy (at default 1)
LeaveOnWithMouse (at default 1)
PanEnabled (at default 1)
RightClickZoneEnabled (at default 1)
ScrollDirection (at default 0)
TapsEnabled (at default 1)
TwoFingerTapEnabled (at default 1)
ZoomEnabled (at default 1)

There's also a subfolder with only one option: Enabled (at default value of 1), which controls whether the pad is usable at all or not.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delay in mouse movement when using both the keyboard & mouse simultaneously](https://superuser.com/questions/819273/delay-in-mouse-movement-when-using-both-the-keyboard-mouse-simultaneously).  In other words, this blocking is a convenience feature (to keep less-experieced users from accidental key presses) which you can switch off.

Comment: @miroxlav Hey, that almost worked!  My touchpad is listed, and *is* a Synaptics model, and does have a palm sensitivity option that appears to be enabled.  Unfortunately, the slider is greyed out and there seems to be no way to adjust it.

Comment: Maybe you can go through entire settings. Some touchpads have option like *block mouse when typing* etc. which can also possibly cause blocking typing when using the mouse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delay in mouse movement when using both the keyboard & mouse simultaneously](https://superuser.com/questions/819273/delay-in-mouse-movement-when-using-both-the-keyboard-mouse-simultaneously)

Comment: So this question now about how to deal with computes where this feature is no allowed to be changed?

Comment: @music2myear Hmm, I think that is a pretty big change.  Maybe I should roll back, close as dupe, and ask a different question.  Thoughts?

Comment: Closing does have a negative flag and as an newish user, it would hurt you more than, say, a little long time user like me. There are also no answers posted yet. Edit this question. Note that you've tried the things in the suggested duplicate and it failed and why. That gives us a good question that keep working on for you.