# Synaptics Touchpad settings missing/not showing

Tags: windows, drivers, touchpad

I want to disable the automatic touchpad delay when using both keyboard and touchpad (Synaptics PrecisionTouchpad) at the same time. This has been asked and answered multiple times, including a [question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/819273/delay-in-mouse-movement-when-using-both-the-keyboard-mouse-simultaneously).

However, I do not have additional Synaptic settings options to disable the delay.

Currently, my mouse properties just looks like this:

[image]

I have tried:

1. Updating my PC to the latest build
2. Updating the driver
3. Uninstalling the driver and reinstalling it
4. Rolling back the driver to a previous version

None of the above worked.

What can I do to enable the menu so that I can adjust the settings? I have also tried looking into the registry: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics, but don't know exactly what to look for, since none of the options there seem to relate to timeouts or delays.

Edit: New screenshot showing more info on current driver:

[image]

Comment: Open Device manager > Mouse and other pointing devices > Right-click on syaptics PS/2 port TouchPad > Update Driver > Browse My computer for drivers > Let me pick... >  uncheck "Show compatible hardware" > Under "Manufacturer" choose Synaptics and double click on " synaptics PS/2 port TouchPad". Restart and check again.

Comment: Hi @SaaranshGarg, I have tried that and restarted my laptop, and unfortunately I still cannot see the additional tab "Device Settings" :( Thank you for trying to help though, most appreciated.

Comment: Your mouse properties image is very partial. Which driver is used for the touchpad?

Comment: The settings you showed are not Synaptics settings (I have a laptop with Synaptics). (1) Are you sure the touchpad is working (no hardware error)?  (2) Update BIOS and the Synaptics driver both.

Comment: @harrymc sorry about the partial pic, I just used it to show that the device settings tab was missing, I have added a new pic showing the driver details.

Comment: @John yes my touchpad works perfectly fine. I haven't tried updating the BIOS as yet, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Strange happenings. Could you in Driver Properties, Details tab, select "Hardware IDs" from the drop-down box, right-click the first ID, select Copy, then paste the string here for verification.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I didn't see a message notification. As requested, here is the string: "HID\VEN_SYNA&DEV_32AE&Col01"